# 0install example feed file for a program compiled for several platforms

Tags: c, installation

Use case: I compiled `hello.c` under Mac, Windows and Linux, let's call the three executables `hellomac`, `hellowin`, `hellotux` and imagine they are packed together in an archive called `hello.zip`. Now let's distribute them using [0install](http://0install.net). Users should be able to go to `http://www.hello.org/Hello.xml` and `0install` should then download `hello.zip` and extract the binary appropriate for the user's platform (e.g. `hellotux` on Linux).

Has anyone got an example `0install` feed file with the necessary incantations for such a situation? I went through the tutorials but was unable to set up the necessary XML correctly... Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why would I want to download three times the size of the program I need?

Comment: You are right, indeed it makes no sense. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

As Bo said in the comment, it would make more sense to have three zip files, one for each platform. Then the XML lists each of them, e.g.

```
<implementation arch='Linux-i386' ...>
  <archive href='.../hello-linux-i386.zip' size='...'/>
</implementation>
<implementation arch='Windows-i386' ...>
  <archive href='.../hello-win-i386.zip' size='...'/>
</implementation>
```

You might find these documents useful:

- http://0install.net/templates.html -- example "hello world" C source package
- http://0install.net/0compile.html -- compiling to get a binary
- http://0install.net/0release-binaries.html -- compiling to multiple targets at release time

However, if you really do want a single zip with three binaries (e.g. because you're making a feed for an existing zip archive), use three `<implementation>` elements with the same `<archive>` but different `main` attributes. Make sure you use a different `id` for each one (the default tools use the hash of the implementation as its ID, but that won't work if they're all the same archive).

Personally, even in that case I would split the big zip into three though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Thomas and Bo for the hints. Now I understand how to combine the archives logically.

Recipe:

Create an archive for each platform. Then with `0publish-gui` first "create group" and then click "add archive" repeatedly for each platform-specific archive. Specify the URL of the archive but don't download it since you have it already: use the "Local copy" button instead to help `0publish-gui` figure out the archive size and the SHA digest. Finally upload everything to your webserver.

Here is my simple Hello.xml file, to help others getting started. Windows complains about an "error in XML (11,21)" but the same XML works under Linux and Mac OS X. The Unices win 2:1 :-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='interface.xsl'?>
<interface uri="http://www.hello.org/Hello.xml" xmlns="http://zero-install.sourceforge.net/2004/injector/interface">
  <name>Hello</name>
  <summary>Hello, world!</summary>
  <description>
Hello, world program</description>
  <homepage>http://www.hello.org</homepage>
  <category>Utility</category>
  <needs-terminal/>
  <group arch="*-*" released="today" version="0.1">
    <implementation arch="Linux-x86_64" id="sha1new=aadb5dca492691888bb5d846f23a2b208a9b7d9e" license="Public Domain" main="hellotux" released="2012-06-29" version="0.1">
      <archive href="http://www.hello.org/hello_tux.zip" size="3298" type="application/zip"/>
    </implementation>
    <implementation arch="MacOSX-x86_64" id="sha1new=8a6c3f898fb938532b4dfd55000507e806524ce7" license="Public Domain" main="hellomac" released="2012-06-29" version="0.1">
    <archive href="http://www.hello.org/hello_mac.zip" size="1637" type="application/zip"/>
  </implementation>
    <implementation arch="Windows-x86_64" id="sha1new=8f8a5cd1aeb4771acaa2017e1054e89d7c11facc" license="Public Domain" main="hello.exe" released="2012-06-29" version="0.1">
    <archive href="http://www.hello.org/hello_win.zip" size="26131" type="application/zip"/>
  </implementation>
  </group>
</interface>
<!-- Base64 Signature (omitted) -->
```

Comment: Note: this bug report is at https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3538972&group_id=76468&atid=547191

Comment: Yes, it was me who submitted that bug report. In the meantime I could "fix" the problem by deinstalling and reinstalling ZeroInstall itself, now it works as intended.